# How can I add horizontal margin on <thead>, make <thead> appear narrower than <tbody>?

Tags: css

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAfFG.png)

(The grey section is `thead`, white section with grey border-bottom is `tr` in `tbody`)

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

thead {
  background: #ddd;
}

tbody tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th,
td {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: start;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sam</td>
      <td>24</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to add a 8px margin left/right around `thead`, while there should be no spacing around tbody.

I have tried adding margin/padding to `thead`, but neither worked. I also attempted adding margin-left to the first element of `thead`, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Please provide minimal example with HTML and CSS. Have you tried `thead th {padding: 0 8px}`?

Comment: @Justinas Sorry, just added the codepen link.

Comment: a Codepen link is not a suitable or acceptable replacement for a [repro]. Questions must be sefl-containing and not rely on an external resource. If the link changes, the Codepen is removed, or the content of the Codepen changes, the question will lose its value.

Comment: If possible can you provide any screenshot for visualization?, How should it look?

Comment: Still, it's not confirm what you wanna achieve. From what I understand if you want to add margin/padding in thead just add "display: table-caption;" property and then add margin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Margins does not really make sense and does not work for table elements.

What you can do is increase padding for first and last elements of `thead th`:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tbody tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

td {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: start;
}

thead tr th {
  padding: 0;
}

thead tr div {
    background: #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
}

thead tr th:first-child {
    padding-left: 8px;
}

thead tr th:last-child {
    padding-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><div>name</div></th>
            <th><div>age</div></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sam</td>
            <td>24</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: My issue is to add margin to the sides of thead, making it appear narrower than tbody. It's not about adding padding to the th elements within thead.

Comment: Add paddings to `th` and wrap content in `div` that you will style as if it were plain `th`

Comment: Please check my edit of answer

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you want to achieve, but perhaps adding an 8px white border to the table will do what you want?

```css
body {
  background: #888;
}

table {
  background: white;
  border: 8px solid white;
}

thead {
    background: #ddd;
}

tbody tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th,
td {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: start;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sam</td>
            <td>24</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Or instead, you could use another element inside your `<th>` cells and apply left and right margins on the first and last of them.

```css
body {
  background: #888;
}

table {
  background: white;
}

tbody tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th,
td {
    width: 100px;
    text-align: start;
}

th p, td {
    padding: 10px;
}

th p {
  margin: 0;
  background: #ddd;
}

th:first-child p {
  margin-left: 8px;
}

th:last-child p {
  margin-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><p>name</p></th>
            <th><p>age</p></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sam</td>
            <td>24</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I want to make `thead` appear narrower than `tbody`.

Comment: I've expanded my answer to include a second option -- using another element inside your `<th>` cells and setting a margin on that.